# Docker postgres connection refused when trying to pg_restore

Tags: linux, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

Internal connection between my Spring Boot app and postgres db works fine but when I want to connect to db through init_database.sh and pg_restore I get `pg_restore: error: connection to server at "db" (192.168.224.2), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?`. In this .sh script I use the same host and port as in application.properties (where connection works fine as I said before).

I simply want to do a pg_restore from init_database.sh in my Docker container.

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    hostname: db
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    command: -c 'max_connections=250'
    ports:
      - "5430:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: endlessblow_db
      POSTGRES_USER: kuba
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
    volumes:
      - ./init.dump:/init.dump
      - ./init_database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_database.sh
    restart: always
    
  app:
    container_name: app
    image: 'endlessblow-server:latest'
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
    depends_on:
    - db
```

init_database.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
pg_restore --no-privileges --no-owner -h db -p 5432 -U kuba -d endlessblow_db init.dump
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/endlessblow_db
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/endlessblow_db
spring.datasource.username=kuba
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

How to solve that? Thank you!

Comment: The init script runs inside the database container and you can probably delete the `pg_restore -h` and `-p` options.  If the dump file is in SQL text format, you might even be able to mount the file directly into `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (make sure to give it a `*.sql` extension) and avoid the script entirely.

Comment: The script runs before the database is put into its final configuration where it listens on the network.  If you remove the '-h db' then it will connect over the local socket.

Answer (score -1):

in config of service "app", try following:

```
app:
  ...
  depends_on:
    - db
  links:
    - db
```

without links, docker network will isolate containers without explicitly exposing them to one another.

Comment: `links:` are an obsolete option related to first-generation Docker networking.  It's usually safe to _delete_ `links:` without changing anything else.